# Unable to resolve class field in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using some forms to retrieve some data from a checkbox with some `choices` that are dynamically generated. Here is my code:

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(label='text', max_length=1000)
    products = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label='product',
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, choices, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.products.choices = choices
```

And when I call the object I get the following error:

```
'PostForm' object has no attribute 'products'
```

Anybody knows how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: typo on product? without the s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be accessing the `self.fields` dict.

```
self.fields['products'].choices = choices
```

Comment: I've change it and the `cleaned_data` is always empty, but `data` has all the values:

Comment: Please don't completely change your question after people have answered it. I reverted the change; now please ask a new question for the new problem.

Comment: I've created an other question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225808/unable-to-get-post-data-in-a-multiplechoicefield-with-django